# Ghostscript installation issue on .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ghostscript, ghostscript.net

I followed a ton of SO guides in order to install Ghostscript in my MVC C# app but I cannot make the code below be recognized. It keeps saying "GhostscriptRasterizer could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
public ActionResult PDFToImages(string pdfFilePath)
        {
            //...

            using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer())
            {
                //...
            }

            //...
        }
```

I am using Visual Studio and here's what I've already tried:

- Get the .exe file from https://www.ghostscript.com/download.html and installed it. Then manually include gsdll32.dll in my project as "content" (menu: Add existing item);
- On Visual Studio went to "Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Manage NuGet Packages for solution" and then installed Ghostscript.NET by Josip Habjan.
- Also on NuGet Package Manager tried to install Ghostscript dlls by Matthieu - Get an error "Failed to add reference to 'gsdll32'. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."
- On Package Manager Console did "Install-Package Ghostscript -Version 9.2.0" and got also the error above

Comment: I imagine that Ghostscript.NET wants the 64-bit version of Ghostscript. Try installing that. Do please read the license to ensure you are complying with its provisions. You might also get more help by using the ghostscript.net tag instead of the ghostscript tag.

Comment: @KenS Thanks for your answer. Also tried that without luck. Can you please confirm that I am following the correct procedure to install the DLL? I've installed Ghostscript on Windows, then went to Visual Studio right click on my project and Add>Existing Item and choose the file from the installation folder gs\gs9.52\bin\gsdll64.dll . (added the suggested tag also, thanks)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help you with that at all, I have no idea how ghostscript.net works. Though I cannot see any reason why you would add the DLL to the project, I thought that ghostscript.net loaded it using the system environment variables. This is one reason I suggested adding the ghostscript.net tag, I'm afraid I don't know anything about that project, its not part of the Ghostscript open source project, its maintained by a different author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your objective is to make uso of Ghostscript .NET directly, you would not need to reference the original Ghostscript DLL from your project (as I said, until you desire to do so).

I tested Ghostscript .NET over Windows 7 and windows 10, with Visual Studio Community 2017 simply following these steps:

1. Install **Ghostscript 9.52 for Windows (32 bits)**.
2. Using **Nuget package manager**, added **Ghostscript .NET** to my solution.
3. Include **using** code lines, as required (main namespace and **Rasterizer** for your case should work, I use **Processor**, in addition):

```
    using Ghostscript.NET;
    using Ghostscript.NET.Processor;
    using Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer;
```

I have checked in a new Console Application project the *using* clause (which makes use of Rasterizer class) that you have provided, and does not return any error, if I perform these steps previously.

Please, try again repeating the actions mentioned, and let me know if you manage to use Ghostscript that way.